# 415 Error when posting JSON in Java with Jersey

Tags: java, json, jersey, http-status-code-415

I have looked through Google, and at other questions here, to no avail.  They all say the same things... Import the .jar for jersey-json (done), add the dependency to pom.xml (done) and add the POJOMappingFeature to the web.xml (done), yet I am still unable to access the Restful web service with JSON going into, or coming out of the server.

web.xml

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
<display-name>My Application</display-name>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>my.app</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

pom.xml

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>
    </dependency>
```

Service method:

```
@POST
@Path("/request")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public ResponseInfo Request(RequestInfo requestInfo)
```

Both ResponseInfo and RequestInfo have @XmlRoot and @XmlElement annotations.
I am running locally on Tomcat 7.0.33 and get the following error:

```
SEVERE: A message body reader for Java class           
my.app.RequestInfo, and Java type class my.app.RequestInfo, and MIME media type
application/json was not found.
The registered message body readers compatible with the MIME media type are:
application/json ->
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONJAXBElementProvider$App
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONRootElementProvider$App
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONListElementProvider$App
*/* ->
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FormProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StringProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ByteArrayProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FileProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.InputStreamProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DataSourceProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLJAXBElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ReaderProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DocumentProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$StreamSourceReader
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$SAXSourceReader
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$DOMSourceReader
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONJAXBElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLListElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootObjectProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.EntityHolderReader
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONRootElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONListElementProvider$General
```

Comment: Did you forget to include the HTTP verb on your service method, or do you not have one in the actual code as well?

Comment: Updated question... It was in code, not in copy/paste

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are missing JacksonJsonProvider.class for marshalling and unmarshalling that can be found in jackson-core-asl-1.9.2.jar

Answer (score 1):

You might need to add an ObjectMapper class.
For example in my Jersey-Java sample app, when my client wants to create an account, this is the logic that is run on the server:

```
@Path("/makeStormpathAccount")
public class StormpathAccount {

    @POST
    public void createAccount(UserAccount userAccount) throws Exception {
```

Notice how I have (UserAccount userAccount) as the parameters of my route method. The UserAccount class looks like this:

```
import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonProperty;

public class UserAccount {

    @JsonProperty
    private String first_name;

    @JsonProperty
    private String last_name;

    @JsonProperty
    private String user_name;

    @JsonProperty
    private String email;

    @JsonProperty
    private String password;


    public String getFirstName() {
        return first_name;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return last_name;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return user_name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
}
```

and it uses this ObjectMapper class to actually map the data:

```
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.SerializationConfig;

import javax.ws.rs.ext.ContextResolver;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

@Provider
public class MyObjectMapperProvider implements ContextResolver<ObjectMapper> {

    final ObjectMapper defaultObjectMapper;

    public MyObjectMapperProvider() {
        defaultObjectMapper = createDefaultMapper();
    }

    @Override
    public ObjectMapper getContext(Class<?> type) {
        return defaultObjectMapper;
    }

    private static ObjectMapper createDefaultMapper() {
        final ObjectMapper result = new ObjectMapper();
        result.configure(SerializationConfig.Feature.INDENT_OUTPUT, true);

        return result;
    }

}
```

to convert the JSON being sent from the client, straight into Java!

sources: https://github.com/rkazarin/sample-jersey-webapp/tree/master/src/main/java/com/sample/jersey/app

Answer (score 0):

Try adding [Genson library](http://owlike.github.io/genson/) to your classpath.
It is a java library doing conversion between java and json. It works quite well with Jersey. You only need to drop the jar into your classpath.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem, and changing @XmlElement to @XmlRootElement in RequestInfo solved my problem.

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
```